# GitLab Pipeline - FastLane issue Builds cannot be assigned to this internal group

Tags: reactjs, gitlab-ci, fastlane

I have a GitLab pipeline setup to build and then upload a iOS reactive native application to TestFlight, using Fastlane. It seems to work ok up to the point where it tries to run the action upload_to_testflight and then errors with the message "Spaceship::UnexpectedResponse: [!] Builds cannot be assigned to this internal group. - Cannot add internal group to a build." It had been working and now has randomly stopped working.

Due to the fact it had been working and suddenly stopped working, I have tried updating the FastLane version from 2.210.0 to 2.217.0, but I still get exactly the same error as before.

Comment: I have this issue too. Jenkins pipeline, same fastlane version 2.217.0. Have you considered raising a github issue in the fastlane repo?